# Estimation of the entropy of keys derived from truly random numbers

Tags: key-derivation, entropy

**NOTE:** This question is based on my assumption that $X$ is a "truly random number" if and only if it's length measured in bits is equal to its entropy measured in bits. In other words, when every bit of $X$ has been generated by a random coin toss.

Suppose I have a truly random number $R$ of size 256 bits (256 bits of entropy), and a truly random number $S$ of length $n * 256$, where $n$ is some natural number, so it has $n * 256$ bits of entropy.

I now derive four keys $T_1$ to $T_4$ from $R$

- $T_1 = \text{concat}(R, \text{... n times ...}, R)$
- Calculate $t_1 = \text{sha256}(R)$, $t_2 = \text{sha256}(t_1)$, ..., $t_n = \text{sha256}(t_{n-1})$, and do $T_2=\text{concat}(t_1, ..., t_n)$.
- $T_3$ is calculated same as above, but using HMAC instead of sha256.
- $T_4 = \text{hkdf_expand}(R, \text{null}, n * 256 / 8)$.

Finally, I calculate $K_i = T_i\text{ xor }S$.

How many bits of entropy does $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_3$ and $K_4$ have?

**My happy guesses:**

- $T1$ will have as most as many entropy as $R$, since concatenation by repetition doesn't increase the entropy of the output, but I suspect it won't decrease it either.
- $\text{sha256}$ and $\text{HMAC}$ are believed to preserve the bits of entropy of the input, but since the process to construct $T_2$ and $T_3$ is deterministically calculated from $R$, the entropy of $T_2$ and $T_3$ will be roughly equivalent to $T1$.
- No idea about $T_4$. I guess the benefits of $\text{hkdf_expand}$ kick in when its input is not a truly random number.

About every $K_i$, I'm not sure. I recently learned that XORting two truly random numbers gives a truly random number, so the bits of entropy of the output is still its length, but since the $T_i$s aren't truly random numbers anymore, I don't know what will happen here.

My intuition tells me that the entropy of $S$ will be preserved ($n * 128$ bits), because $K_i$ is equivalent to encrypt $T_i$ using $S$ as a one-time pad key, making $T_i$ or $S$ theoretically unbreakable, so $K_i$ is still a truly random number.

Comment: Hiya! Err, I'm confused. Can you simplify the question given that you have access to truly random numbers? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PaulUszak I have replaced my final note with my own guesses, as example of the level of detail I expect.

Comment: @PaulUszak We can say my question is mostly theoretical.

Comment: Issues A) \[snip, question fixed\]. B) HMAC needs a key. C) Strictly speaking, "How many bits of entropy does $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_3$ and $K_4$ have?" asks something moot, since bitstrings don't have entropy (or have none); _the process_ that builds them has a well-defined entropy. D) The entropy of the processes that build $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_3$ and $K_4$ depends on if $R$ and $S$ are independent. In the affirmative, it's \[excessive hint snipped\] thanks to "I calculate $K_i=T_i\text{ xor }S$" and $T_i$ being a function of $R$.

Comment: @fgrieu I meant each $T_i$ depends entirely on $R$; and yes I know the entropy depends on the process, not the number. I can get the number 5 by a random pick, or by 2 + 3 where 2 and 3 are random numbers, or by 2 + 3 where 2 and 3 are known numbers. The first process will have 3 bits of entropy, the 2nd process probably too (a guess of mine, because adding random numbers changes the statistical distribution, but it's still a random process), and the third process 0 bits of entropy.

Comment: @fgrieu and yes, being more precise now, my question was about what happens with the entropy of the process up to  each $K_i$ when I use things like concat, sha256 or hkdf_expand over a key with less entropy ($R$) combined later with a key with more entropy ($S$), but yes after your first comment I understand that XORting doesn't destroy entropy as far as $S$ and $T_i$ are totally unrelated, so the fact that $R$ has less entropy than $S$ doesn't risks the security of $K_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> XORing two truly random numbers gives a truly random number

No. Counterexample: $S$ uniformly random, $S\oplus S$ is the all-zero bitstring of the same size as $S$, and is not uniformly random (unless $S$ is empty).

What holds is: **XORing two *independent* values of the same size, *at least one of which* is a truly random number, yields a truly random number.**

In the exercise, $S$ is uniformly random, and $T_i$ depends only on $R$ (and an unstated key for HMAC in the case of $T_3$, but let's ignore that), and everything points at $R$ being independent of $S$. Thus $T_i$ being independent of $S$.

The above, size of things, and $K_i$ being built as $K_i=T_i\oplus S$, are enough to conclude about

> how many bits of entropy does $K_1$, $K_2$, $K_3$ and $K_4$ have

and this is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you. Can I conclude that since I have already truly random numbers as input, in order to expand $R$ to construct $T_i$, more complex and computationally expensive operations like sha256 or hkdf_expand gives me nothing (considering that I will XORted it with $S$ later) and just repeating $R$ (to build $T_1$) is enough?

Comment: @sanscrit. The point is that regardless of the process that builds a $T_i$ of the same size as $S$, and independently of uniformly random $S$ (including, builds $T_i$ as a function of $R$ independent of $S$), one can conclude about the entropy in $K_i=T_i\oplus S$. That' not exactly what you state above. In particular, you don't care that $R$ is uniformly random, only that it's independent of $S$ (and that $S$ is uniformly random).